# Powershell AD user search by name and OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I receive task on studies to create command that will find a specific users in specific `OU` in Active Directory.

More precise, find all persons that name is `A*` and are located in `OU` `*es`.

After hours of researching I created such commands:

For finding all `A*` users:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {name -like "A*"}
```

For finding all `*es` `OU`

```
Get-ADObject -filter {OU -like "*es"}
```

And I don't have idea how to connect those outputs.

I was thinking about such resolutions, but they don't work for me.

```
$var = Get-ADObject -filter {OU -like "*es"} | Select DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -filter {name -like "A*"} -SearchBase $var
```

Or

```
Get-ADUser -filter {name -like "A*" -and OU -like "*es"}
```

I'm lost, please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first use the *server* filter to get all `A*`users and then filter the `OU` on the *client* using the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) cmdlet:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Name -like 'A*'} | Where-Object DistinguishedName -like '*OU=*es*'
```

If you know all your `OU` you want to filter, consider using the `-SearchBase` Parameter. [More information here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx).

Comment: *Thanks*, this is what i was looking for. I know that it was something to do with pipe, but i didn't know how to connect it.